# Converting an array of object to another with javascript's reduce method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to add events to the existing date so i think i need to change my json structure something like below. I tried to achieve it via reduce as shown below

I want to convert this array of object

```
"sunday": [
    "...",
    7,
    14,
    21,
    28
  ]
```

To

```
    {  
   "sunday":[  
      {  
         "7":[  
            "event1",
            "event2",
            "event3"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "14":[  
            "event3",
            "event4",
            "event5"
         ]
      },
      {
          "21":[]
      },
      {
          "28":[]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the data that has event's detail,

```
{
    "data": [
       { "date": "7", 
         "events": ["event1", "event2", "event3"] 
       },
       { "date": "14", 
         "events": ["event3", "event4", "event5"] 
       },
]
}
```

What i tried and failed,

```
attachEventsToTheDate(week_days) {
    var answer = [week_days].reduce(function(result, item, index) {
      var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
      var value = item[key][index];
      var obj = {};
      obj[key] = [obj[key]];
      console.log('obj is', JSON.stringify(obj));
      // JSON.stringify(obj);
      // result.push(obj);
      return result;
    }, {}); //an empty array
  }
```

Comment: Where do *event1*, *event2*, etc from? These are not from the original array

Comment: where does `"event1"` etc come from?

Comment: It comes from an api

Comment: you can simply hardcode it

Comment: sure, it comes from an API ... but you're reducing an array that doesn't have the data, and expecting  the data to magically appear?

Comment: you can hardcode the dummy data

Comment: Why are you putting `week_days` INSIDE of an array before reducing it?  Is it not already an array?  The way it is written, the reducer will only run once: on the `week_days` variable (which you put inside of an array)

Comment: Hi, all added the event's data

Comment: @Jaromanda X , we have the data now. Can you answer now?

Comment: Your event data is about different months and years, so how do you plan to filter this? It looks like you have one particular month in view and only want to assign events that belong to that particular month to the weeks object. If so, where do you indicate which month you are interested in? Could you clarify?

Comment: I changed events data model. It is now only of date.

Comment: Why would the events from the event with date "9" end up in the sunday object at value 14? Or where do the values "event-one", "event-two", ... come from? Can you please explain the logic or even better, provide a consistent example?

Comment: @ trincot edited the question. Should be clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` it:

```js
var sunday = [ 7, 14, 21, 28 ]
var data = [ { "date": "7", "events": ["event1", "event2", "event3"] }, { "date": "14", "events": ["event3", "event4", "event5"] }]

console.log(sunday.map(x => {
    var actual = data.find(y => y.date == x);
    if(actual) {
        return {[x]: actual.events}
    } else {
        return {[x]: []}
    }
}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The object structure you desire to have will not be very efficient to work with, but here it is:

```js
function groupEvents(week_days, events) {
    const numToDay = []; // Extra index into the week_days nested objects
    // Create a new week_days object
    week_days = Object.assign(...Object.keys(week_days).map( day => 
        ({ [day]: week_days[day].filter(Number).map(num => 
            ({ [num]: numToDay[num] = [] })
        )})
    ));
    // Inject the events data into it
    for (const data of events.data) {
        // Skip if this day does not exist in the original week_days structure
        if (!numToDay[data.date]) continue;
        numToDay[data.date].push(...data.events);
    }
    return week_days;
}

const week_days = {sunday: ["...", 7, 14, 21, 28]},
      events = {data: [
          { date:  "7", events: ["event1", "event2", "event3"] },
          { date: "14", events: ["event4", "event5"] } 
      ]};

const res = groupEvents(week_days, events);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### A more generic solution

The `week_days` object seems to be a translation of a certain month. If one has just the month, the `week_days` structure can be derived from it. So the key information is really your `events` object. If you can turn that object (as specified in your *original* question, i.e. with year and month info included) into something grouped by year-month combinations, and then produce for each combination a `week_days` kind of structure, you'll have all you need.

At the same time it seems more logical to use the day numbers as keys in the week_days nested objects.

Here is a demo on how you can do that:

```js
const events = {
    "data": [
       { "year": "2017", "month": "january", "date": "16", 
         "events": ["event1", "event2", "event3"] 
       },
       { "year": "2017", "month": "january", "date": "8", 
         "events": ["event4", "event5"] 
       },
    ]
};

function groupEvents(events) {
    const dayNames = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 
                      'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']; 
    return events.data.reduce( (acc, o) => {
        const key = o.month.toLowerCase() + " " + o.year;
        if (!acc[key]) {
            acc[key] = Object.assign(...dayNames.map(day => ({ [day]: {} })));
            const dt = new Date("1 " + key);
            const month = dt.getMonth();
            while (dt.getMonth() === month) {
                acc[key][dayNames[dt.getDay()]][dt.getDate()] = [];
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1);
            }
        }
        const dt = new Date(o.date + " " + key);
        acc[key][dayNames[dt.getDay()]][dt.getDate()].push(...o.events);
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
const res = groupEvents(events);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If now you want to have only the data of the month January 2017 (for example), you can just take it out of the result from the above script as follows:

```
const january2017_week_days = res["january 2017"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. I have function to get month and year. I have changed the events data model which is only of date and events. I want the exact answer of how i mentioned.

Comment: The number 9 does not occur in the orginal `week_days` object. Is that really how you want it? You want to ignore anything that originally was in the `week_days` object?

Comment: That should be 14.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and make it consistent?

Comment: Thanks. I also want 21 and 28 to be an empty array

Comment: if there is no events, then the date should be an empty array.

Comment: Could you please update your question and make clear what your *exact* requirements are? Please give 2 or three examples that clearly illustrate what you want to happen in such cases.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @trincot. I had to accept guijob's answer as it is shortest. God bless you.

Comment: OK, but his solution works in *O(n²)* time complexity instead of *O(n)*. Also he starts out with a simplified data structure. He has no `week_days` object with a `sunday` property, but has a `sunday` variable (which relieves him from dealing with other days as I did), and has no `events` object with `data` property (which is just a minor thing). No problem for me though.